Why is a transaction created without the @Transactional annotation?
I have a execute() method that calls 2 methods of a service that makes queries to the database. I need to have only 1 transaction for the entire execution of this method, within which entities would be blocked for other transactions. Here is an example of this method, which should open a transaction:
public class JobService {

     @Autowired
     private RequestService requestService

     @Transactional
     public void execute() {
         List<Request> entitiesForProcessing =
         requestService.entityListByStatus(requestStatus.CREATED.getCode(), MAX_PROCESSING_ENTITY_COUNT);
         for (Request request: entitiesForProcessing ) {
         //process each record
         requestService.saveOrUpdateRequest(request);
     }
}

Service method that retrieves entities from the database with a lock (without the @Transactional annotation):
public List<Request> entityListByStatus(Integer status, int maxResultCount) {
     DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Request.class);
     criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", status));
     criteria.setLockMode(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
     LOGGER.info("Select Request entities by status {}", status);
     return dao.listByCriteria(criteria, maxResultCount);
}

The above method actually locks lines for the duration of the execute() method, but the saveOrUpdateRequest() method itself opens the transaction, despite the lack of an annotation. This results in the new transaction being unable to update the records because they are locked by another transaction. A service method that should not open a transaction, but does:
public class RequestService {

     @Autowired
     private Dao dao;

     public void saveOrUpdateRequest(Request request) {
         try {
             dao.saveOrUpdate(gibddRequest);
         } catch (RuntimeException e) {
             LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
         }
     }
}

The dao method uses Hibernate to access the database:
public void saveOrUpdate(Object entity) {
     Session currentSession = getCurrentSession();
     currentSession.saveOrUpdate(entity);
}

How can I make it so that there is only 1 isolated transaction created by the execute() method?
I've tried all possible propagation options, but the transaction still opens. In this case, no exceptions occur. Also, I tried selecting records without blocking, in which case the saveOrUpdateRequest() method can update entities, but only if @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) is specified in the annotation parameters.
